# If any way to change the design and position for javascript Alert Message window

Tags: javascript, html, css

In default Javascript Alert Message window design and position need to change. if any possible methods available mean please help me.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to change the design of the default Alert Window. You will have to use custom UI elements called **modals** to circumvent this problem.

Here is a link to [modals in Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/).

Answer (score 0):

Use the new HTML5 `<dialog>` element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog or http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/forms.html#the-dialog-element.

However browser support is spotty (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog).